# iOS / Readability

Tags: ios, rss, readability

I'm working on an RSS reader app and I'd like to provide a consistent article experience for my users (i.e. the new Safari Reader). Is there an API that would apply here? I'm aware of Readability but I'm not sure if that is what I need.

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961509/readability-in-my-application/14290141

Answer (score 2):

just was doing some research for my app, heres what I've found. couldn't post all the links cause I'm new, but easily googleable

Read, Clear Read API: http://readapp.net/pub.html

Instapaper itself. Simple and Full API

Readability

RTCOOL

Feeds api

Boilerpipe

Goose

An overview of text extraction algorithms: http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/03/text-extraction.php

best of luck!