# Readability in my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I wonder how to open some article using 'reading view' of Readability - just like Tweetbot is doing it. But without sending article to my account and save to queue.

Displaying article using Readability like in Reeder is not so easy, right? I would have to write to company and ask them for access to their parser?

Maybe is there any other good way to parse articles using Readability. I have read something about javascript parser, but don't know too much.

Could you help me?

Comment: Did you at least read the official documentation or consult the official website and blog of the Readability application? For example I just Googled it and found [this article from their official blog](http://blog.readability.com/2012/10/new-ios-developer-tools/). And there is probably more documentation around on their website.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Readability mobilizer for this. You will get a cleaned up version of any article, in the Readability styling:

```
http://www.readability.com/m?url=http://{URLOFTHEARTICLE}
```

Just prepare the URL and load it in your UIWebView. I'm escaping the parameter values. Here is how it looks in action:

[http://www.readability.com/m?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnn.com%2F2013%2F01%2F11%2Fshowbiz%2Ftv%2Fgolden-globes-tv-vineyard%2Findex.html%3Fhpt%3Dhp_abar](http://www.readability.com/m?url=http://www.cnn.com/2013/01/11/showbiz/tv/golden-globes-tv-vineyard/index.html?hpt=hp_abar)

Comment: Could you tell me yet, what to do, to display good text encoding? 
http://readability.com/m?url=http://fakty.interia.pl/fakty_dnia/news/rzeczpospolita-gen-janicki-moze-odejsc-z-bor,1881332/bcdb7018df090809d64cddc48e7178c6 It makes http://cl.ly/image/2L0l3A3d3q3K

Comment: From what I see it doesn't work on mobile Safary too. Which means that the problem is probably outside your reach. Is this the same with other Polish sites too?

Comment: When I use this on websites the content is not up to date? Do you know what causes this?

Answer (score 1):

Both Reeder and Tweetbot use the Content API of Readability (You can see them listed on the [Apps and Tools Page](https://www.readability.com/apps)). You're right that you have to send an email to Readability to gain access to the content API. Parsing articles on the server is not exactly free for them, so they want to make sure there is a relationship with folks that directly access the parser.

Check out [the API docs](https://www.readability.com/developers/api) for more details. Special attention to the third paragraph:

> If you'd like access to the Readability parser directly, the Content API is available upon request. [Contact us](https://www.readability.com/contact) if you're interested.

Alternatively, you can check out the [original Javascript bookmarklet](https://code.google.com/p/arc90labs-readability/), though it is using an older parsing algorithm (which is actually what Apple based Safari's Reader off of... check out the Acknowledgements in Safari).