# Display html articles in a easy to read format

Tags: html, readability

I have looked at the [readability api](http://readability.com/developers/api) which is useful to display data in a clean format on a html webpage. I am passing a Url to http://www.readability.com/read?url= to display the data. I am initially directed to a page where I can choose to view the info using readability is there any way I can directly view the content in a neat fashion without going through the actual re-direct?

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961509/readability-in-my-application/14290141

Answer (score -1):

take a look at Readability's API: http://www.readability.com/developers/api

Before you implement your code, you have to create an API Key on their website.