# "Reader" Version for UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uikit

I’m planning on using a UIWebView for my app, and making it more user friendly by having a “reader” version of the webpage. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Here’s an example taken from the reddit app that displays a regular webpage, then when you press a button, it transforms the page into a “reader” version. (like how safari does it). Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't include code or an attempt at code.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any library or methods available that turns a UIWebView into reader friendly version, not sure what kind of code you are referring to. The pictures should more than help in showing you what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t know of any API for `UIWebView` or a third-party library, but many apps use [Readability Mobilizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961509/readability-in-my-application), [Instapaper Mobilizer](http://mobilizer.instapaper.com/m), or [Google Mobilizer](http://www.google.com/gwt/n). Just pass your URL to one of these services, and load the resulting page.